# Jaspersoft se bloquea al diseñar reporte

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporte, jaspersoft, bloqueo

Solicito de su apoyo para solucionar un error. Inserte una tabla para mi reporte, cuando intento modificarla se bloquea Jaspersoft, no puedo cambiar tamaños de columnas, letra, ni nada. Reinicie unas 10 veces Jaspersoft, instalé la ultima versión (6.17) pero sucedió lo mismo. Ejecuto mi Query en pgadmin (postgresql) y hace la consulta en segundos, no presenta problemas. Además, he creado el reporte varias veces desde cero y me pasa lo mismo. No sé que mas hacer, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Intenta añadir imagenes de lo que te sucede especificamente, para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Agrega el código (jrxml) a la pregunta.